# Need to get all duplicates plus see the parent and child

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a query that is returning me all duplicates. I want to be able to see who their primarytopic is and the topic for each row.

```
select pubproductid, primarytopic, topic, count(pubproductid)
from q
group by pubproductid,primarytopic,topic
having count (pubproductid) > 1;

Getting this.

column_3    column_4    primarytopic    pubproductid    topic
2           2           xu              201             do

Expecting this

column_3    column_4    primarytopic    pubproductid    topic
2           2           xu              201             do
2           2           xl              201             da
```

Comment: Can you post the data that produces this result?

Comment: You have posted the result of your query and what you are expecting but not the input data that produced it. We need the input so we can see why the output was generated.

Comment: I am querying on a table that has duplicate rows.

Comment: Yes. And we need to see the input data, to tell you what you need to do, to get what you need.

Comment: are you sure that topic you have more than 1 rows based on that grouping?

Comment: You are grouping by pubproductid as well as aggregating a count of it.  Won't the count of pubproductid always be 1 since you are grouping on it?  I would actually expect no records returned from that query.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some record with pubproductid set to NULL...
If this is the case, remember that

```
count(pubproductid)
```

differs from

```
count(*)
```

because the first doesn't count the NULLs...

Otherwise, please, put your input data, as asked by the other users...